# Subgroups of $M_{3,1}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A \in M_{3} (\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^3=A$. We denote $(G,+)=(M_{3,1}(\mathbb{R}),+)$, $G_0=\{x\in G| AX=O_3 \}$, $G_1=\{x\in G| AX=X \}$, $G_{-1}=\{x\in G| AX=-X \}$.

a) Prove that $G_0,G_1$ and $G_{-1}$ are subgroups of $G$.

This is easy!

b) Prove that for any $X \in G$ there are three matrices $X_0 \in G_0$,$X_1 \in G_1$ and $X_{-1} \in G_{-1}$ uniquely determined such that $X=X_0+X_1+X_{-1}$.

The uniqueness is not hard to prove. ( It's easy to show that if $O_3=X_0+X_1+X_{-1}$ then $X_0=X_1=X_{-1}=O_3$, and the rest is easier.)

For the existence, I don't know very much. Well, it's easy to see that $spec(A) \in \{ -1,0,1 \}$, and $G_k$ is the set of all eigenvectors of k (if k is an eigenvalue of A, else, $G_k= \{ O_3 \}$), for $k=-1,0,1$, but I don't know how to use it (if it can be used here).

c) If there are three matrices $Y_0 \in G_0- \{ O_3 \}$,$Y_1 \in G_1- \{ O_3 \}$ and $Y_{-1} \in G_{-1}- \{ O_3 \}$, then, prove that $G_0,G_1$ and $G_{-1}$ are isomorphic.

Well, we must have $spec(A)= \{ -1,0,1 \}$, but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Hint: For b) you might want to look at "symmetric" combinations of $A$ and apply those to $X$ to get its decomposition. For instance if $D = A^2 - I$, then $ADX = A^3 X - AX = AX - AX = 0$, so $D$ automatically spits out stuff in $G_0$.

Comment: What does $M_{3,1}(\mathbb{R})$ stand for?

Comment: The set of all matrices with real entries with 3 rows and 1 column.

Comment: @Zach: Can you give me more details, please? Thank you!